# I have searched SO ,found some good articles,tried to implement it.Still I haven't found a way to resolve it through PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working with a code in PHP & MySQL with MySQLi. Two .php files are there, in which, array values must be passed from one file to the other,through a function call.

First php file contains the `$data['uid_fk'];` where I need to display the uid_fk from the table student_register, which is retrieved through function call `Welcome_Students($uid)`.

In Second .php file, the desired output is got in the function where I have commented as // Till here I am getting the values correctly, `$csr[40,41,22,43]` respectively. I want to check the values in `$csr($csr[0], $csr[1], $csr[2], $csr[3])` in the Where clause of `SELECT uid_fk FROM student_register WHERE csr IN $matches`. There are more than one uid_fk in the table, I want to display all uid_fk in the welcome_students.php page. How to achieve this output?

1. welcome_students.php

   ```
   <?php

   include"updates.php";     

   $Updates = new Updates();
   $updatesarray=$Updates->Welcome_Students($uid);


   foreach($updatesarray as $data) {
       echo "<br>".$data['uid_fk'];  //i am not getting the value o uid_fk from the table 'student_register' here
   }
   ?>
   ```
2. updates.php

   ```
   <?php

   Class Updates{
      public function Welcome_Students($uid) {
          $q=mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT School_Name FROM school_teacher_reg WHERE csr='$uid'")or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
          while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($q,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
          {
              $Schoolname=$row1[School_Name];
          }
          $q1=mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT csr FROM school_student WHERE sch_name='$Schoolname'")or die(mysqli_error($this->db)); 

          while($row3=mysqli_fetch_array($q1,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
          {
              $csr[]= $row3; // Till here i am getting the values correctly, $csr[40,41,22,43] respectively
          }  

          $matches  = implode(',',$csr); //data value is coming  here   
          $i=mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT * FROM student_register WHERE csr IN $matches") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));  //$i is also wrking 

          if($i) {
              while($ro=mysql_fetch_assoc($i)) {
                  $data1[]= $ro[uid_fk];
              }
          }                           
          return $data1; 
      } 
   }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: Title should be a short description of your issues, not a log book of all you tried to solve the issue. :)

Comment: thanks for correcting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
$matches = implode(',',$csr); //data value is coming  here   
$i = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT * FROM student_register WHERE csr IN $matches")or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
                                                                         ^^^^^^^^ here
```

You need parenthesis for your `IN` clause:

```
$i = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT * FROM student_register WHERE csr IN ( $matches )")or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
```

But you should really not inject values directly into your queries. Instead you should use prepared statements and bind the values.

Comment: The values of csr are coming from database table 'school_student'

Comment: Now its showing "unknown Array in the column " error @jeroen